# data.table subassignment with `on = `

Tags: r, data.table

When making a subassigment,

> the RHS length must either be 1 (single values are ok) or match the LHS length exactly,

as the error message says when rule is not followed.

However, the following works:

```
tab.01 <- data.table( a = 1L:5L, b = 11L:15L )
tab.02 <- data.table( a = c(1L, 1L, 2L), x = c(11L, 12L, 22L) )

tab.01[ tab.02, x := i.x, on = "a"]
#    a  b  x
# 1: 1 11 12
# 2: 2 12 22
# 3: 3 13 NA
# 4: 4 14 NA
# 5: 5 15 NA
```

The column x is not functionally dependent on the column a. Yet, an assignment is made and, if my guess is right, the last element of the subgroup is assigned.

**Can this default behaviour be changed**, e.g. to choose the first element? The following trials do not work:

1. `mult = "first"` has no effect.
2. `tab.01[ tab.02, x := first(i.x), on = "a" ]` assigns the value 11L to all matches.
3. `tab.01[ tab.02, x := first(i.x), on = "a", by = "a"]` 
   results in an error, because `i.x` is not available anymore (or any other column in `i`).
4. `tab.01[ tab.02, x := first(i.x), on = "a", by = .EACHI ]` does not raise an error, but does not fix anything either. The values in the group a reassigned in the order of the rows, hence the last value is kept.

One can use a version of `tab.02` with functionally dependent columns:

```
tab.02[ , y := f_fd(x), by = "a" ] # e.g. f_fd <- data.table::first
tab.01[ tab.02, x := y, on = "a"]
```

Is this the concisest way to perform this task?

Comment: There's [an issue about this](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2022) on the data.table GitHub

Answer (score 2):

I believe there's no built-in method specifically for accomplishing this. However, it is possible to do this update without modifying `tab.02`.

You could create a subset

```
tab.01[tab.02[rowid(a) == 1], x := i.x, on = "a"][]
#    a  b  x
# 1: 1 11 11
# 2: 2 12 22
# 3: 3 13 NA
# 4: 4 14 NA
# 5: 5 15 NA
```

or order before joining

```
tab.01[tab.02[order(-x)], x := i.x, on = "a"][]
#    a  b  x
# 1: 1 11 11
# 2: 2 12 22
# 3: 3 13 NA
# 4: 4 14 NA
# 5: 5 15 NA
```